# How does the test controller get the binaries to the agent during remote execution?

Tags: tfs

I am trying to get a tests to run via remote execution, and I can't find any documentation on how the following:

I understand that when the controller is registered to a team project collection and the agent runs through a lab environment, then a build needs to be attached to the process - and it then makes perfect sense that the controller pulls the dll that contains the tests from this build.

However, what does not make sense to me is in the more simplified scenario:

I have my test solution with a testsetting file, here I define the controller under roles. I also have 1 agent connected to the controller. Now in visual studio when I run the test, it runs this through the controller -> which delegates to the agent. However I have not setup any build.

I'm assuming that visual studio pushes the dll's to the controller when you first run the test. The controller then creates a cache of the dll's? This is just a guess. Is it correct?

I need to know how the internals work because I have not yet got any test to run on a remote controller. So far after much headaches I can only get the scenario to work when the controller and agent and local dev environment are located on the same machine.

All the MSDN documentation talks about the high level reuse, and does not go into any details of the internals.

Comment: DLL should be found under %LocalAppData of the user under which test agent is running%\VSEQT\QTAgent\<Guid>\Deployment.

Comment: Documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx seems very detailed

Comment: @Giulio - that explains where the Agent stores the binaries. I'm interested in where the controller gets the binaries from - thanks through for the links.

Comment: In your senario you are doing manual testing. You need Standard Environments to do automation: http://nakedalm.com/execute-tests-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

Answer (score 1):

You likley want to run the tests automatedly after a deployment. If that is the case then you probably want a TFS integrated experience rather than the Visual Studio client one. The client experience is primarily for load testing at small scale.

Try: http://nakedalm.com/execute-tests-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

In this configuration your app is installed and pre-configured prior to running the tests. The agent then lifts the test assemblies from the build drop.